# How do I get only one row from a list of items in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a non-normalized sales database like this:

```
Invoice  Item     Price  Total_Sale
-------  ----     -----  ----------
565      Nails    1.25   6.25
565      Hammer   5.00   6.25
566      Paint    7.95   7.95
...
```

As you can see, the "total_sale" is repeated for *each* line item in the invoice.  Invoice #565 has two items, for a total of $6.25.  Invoice #566 only has one item, the total is $7.95.  The sum(total_sale) for both invoices should be $14.20.

Q: Is there any easy way to get *all* the columns* for just *one* row for each different invoice?  Regardless if the invoice has one, two or one hundred line items?

Comment: Mean you want result like 565 total_sale 12.50,correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 - What do you **really** need here. My answer addresses the specific question you have asked but not really sure why you would want that and there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: Is there any easy way to get all the columns* for just one row for
>   each different invoice?

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT 
      Invoice,
      Item,
      Price,
      Total_Sale,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
      Invoice,
      Item,
      Price,
      Total_Sale
FROM T 
WHERE RN=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple query would be:

```
Select SUM(Price), Invoice, Total_Sale From InvoicesTable
Group By Invoice, Total_Sale
Order By Invoice
```

The item column cannot be included as the group by would yield multiple rows.